# How to run Ubuntu 13.04 with 3D acceleration using intel HD 4000?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, 13.04

When my system boot and try to load Ubuntu, I have only a graphic bug in the screen.

I tried to use the `nomode set` mode and it works, but i don't have 3d acceleration and don´t have any drivers to install.

Answer (score 1):

try creating a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file with this in it

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

then restart or run `sudo service lightdm restart` from a tty `[Ctrl]`+`[Alt]`+`[F2]`
If that works please file a bug report using the command `ubuntu-bug xorg`

Comment: Does not work, when I restart the computer, I have only terminal.

Comment: Try the stuff on this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#X_freeze.2Fcrash_with_intel_driver

Comment: i just noticed a error in the code i posted above, i just fixed it